# Source of Dhyana mantra and Rishi for each Mantra in Sri Rudram

Tags: vedic-chanting, krishna-yajurveda, rudram, dayananda-saraswati

I saw a few pages of the book 'Sri Rudram' by Swami Dayananda Saraswathi. In it, he has mentioned Dhyana, Rishi, and Cchandas for *each* mantra of Sri Rudram.

I believe the Vedic text may not have it. He has also mentioned the benefits of chanting each of these mantras.

As an eager student of the text, I would like to know what will be the source of this information.